# The $_GET code doesnt work properly in php

Tags: php

I have a little problem with my PHP. 
I just wrote a very simple program:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
    ?>
</html>
```

The problem is now, when I try to test this, and I ad for example '?name=Jim' to the url, It should output 'Hello Jim!', but it just outputs nothing...

I wrote the code in notepad++, saved it as 'Test.php' and this is my link: file:///C:/Users/Anthony/test.php?name=Jim

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the fie extenstion ? is PHP installed ?

Comment: The problem is not with the code. It works on my server.

Comment: I use notepad++ with extension PHP

Comment: Show us exactly how you're using it. Get requests have a `?` before the attribute. I.e.: `?name=Jim`

Comment: Are you running it on a local PHP server?

Comment: Ok, so none of the answers below worked. Is PHP installed and properly configured? Is your file extension other than `.php`? @user3599598 are you running via WWW or localhost? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Nitpicking: You should add a `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: You are missing the closing body tag, but that is not the issue here. Content should show up anyway.

Comment: I wrote the code in notepad++, saved it as 'Test.php' and this is my link: file:///C:/Users/Anthony/test.php?name=Jim

Comment: Ah, ok, that cannot work! A file name is _not_ a url! You _MUST_ use http to access the http server and have the script executed. For this you use a url in a web browsers address bar. That is where you want to add the parameter.

Comment: Use `http://localhost/Anthony/test.php?name=Jim` and not `file:///...` @user3599598

Comment: When I use http://localhost/Anthony/test.php?name=Jim it gives me an error 'Webpage not availabe'

Comment: What about `127.0.0.1/Anthony/test.php?name=Jim` @user3599598

Comment: it gives the same error, but the weird thing is, when I enter it in the URL-bar and I hit enter, the part 'name=Jim' disappears...

Comment: or `http://localhost/test.php?name=Jim` @user3599598

Comment: This is weird, I tried uploading the file to my website, and then it works perfectly...

Comment: A localmachine/computer and a (hosted) Website are ***two different animals*** altogether. Don't you have PHP/Apache installed on your computer? @user3599598

Comment: I haven't installed it but I normally don't have to, right? I can just use .php in notepad++, what do I have to install then?

Comment: Consult some of the answers below. One of which is mine where I've outlined what is the actual issue here. @user3599598

Comment: @user3599598 You can certainly edit php files in notepad++. But you'll need a php runtime set up if you want to actually execute any php code. Typically, php is setup to run as an Apache module although it can also be run in other ways. Your web browser can render HTML/CSS/Javascript without a web server, but not php.

Comment: Okay thanks everybody. I'm very very sorry for this stupid question!

Answer (score 2):

> *"This is weird, I tried uploading the file to my website, and then it works perfectly."*

You obviously don't have PHP/Apache installed on your computer and you are trying to access a `.php` file on your computer as if it were a `.html` HTML file that a web browser can access/render properly even if not connected to the Internet or having a Web server setup.

This will render on your computer properly: as `.html` or `.htm` extension

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

    <h1>Hello Jim</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

While this won't display correctly, *as expected*. (as `.php` extension)

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

> *"I haven't installed it but I normally don't have to, right? I can just use .php in notepad++, what do I have to install then?"*

You don't normally have to if you're going to write simple HTML with no PHP (see above codes for example).

**Install one**
As others have already pointed out in some of the answers given, a webserver/PHP/Apache needs to be installed on your computer and properly configured in order to be able to view/parse the files correctly.

A localmachine/computer and a (hosted) Website are ***two different animals*** altogether.

---

Consult the following links: (as found when Googling "how to install a web server on my computer to run php or on a mac")

- **http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php**
- **http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/**

Comment: Thank you, really! I am very very sorry for this stupid question :D

Comment: Not a problem and you're very much welcome. @user3599598 I didn't think it was stupid. When you don't know, you don't know ;-) and that's why we're here to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: If you feel that my answer has solved or has helped you as a resolution, then it's your choice if you want to properly close the question and mark it as being solved by clicking the white tick/checkmark next to my answer till it turns to Green. @user3599598 Otherwise, your question will remain in the unanswered category.

Comment: @user3599598 Do start accepting answers before posting new questions, in order to close the question. You haven't done that yet. That's how the system works here.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about `?` sign

use this `http://yourserver/?name=Jim`

Comment: No, didn't forgot it, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you really get *no* output at all (not even the "Hello"), then there is something wrong with executing that script. You should check the http servers error log file for any hints. Since the script itself does not have any syntax errors I can spot most likely php support is missing in your http servers setup or not configured correctly.

You will need to provide more information about your server setup...

Answer (score 0):

You're not running the file in a php server when you access it with this url:

```
 file:///C:/Users/Anthony/test.php?name=Jim
```

You're just loading the unparsed source. You need to run this through Apache, nginx or some other http server with php support enabled. Also, make sure the web root is pointing to the folder on disk containing `Anthony/test.php`.

You may have noticed that your web browser *can* render HTML/CSS/Javascript when you load a file directly from the hard disk (i.e. with a `file://` url). That's because these are *client side* technologies. For a *server side* technology such as php, you'll need a capable web server to execute it.

Comment: You did a good job to spot the answer others gave in the comments to post it as your own answer :-)

Comment: I responded to the OP's comment (now deleted). This is an original answer.

Comment: Ok, if that really is the case then this answer is fine. Congrats.

Comment: Timestamp says differently. But, this gives a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, it might be that he was typing whilst others gave the answer as comment. Let's be fair :-)

Comment: @arkascha I know. I'm just being *somewhat* silly. Now, it seems like the OP still has a problem. See his/her (new) comment(s) under original question.

Comment: Well @arkascha I'm doing my best under OP's question/comments to help. Asaph needs to work for his potential win lol!

Comment: This is just getting silly. The question should have been closed long ago.

Comment: @arkascha I agree which is what I did a few minutes ago. Voted to close.

Comment: Well @Asaph It seems we've finally found the `root` of the problem. No pun intended lol

Answer (score 0):

Even without `?name=Jim` in url it should output `Hello !`,

Are you sure you have PHP installed ?

If yes then make a new file and write:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If you didn't get anything then i don't think it's installed

Answer (score 0):

You need a local web server installed on your computer.

You can get [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for windows, or [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) for Mac.